# How does Naga Rejuvenation work?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The 5E MM says Guardian and Spirit Naga can come back from the dead but the details are murky- does what's left of the Naga's body 'regenerate' or does the creature form a new body? Would moving its remains to another location cause the Naga to reform in that location?

Answer (score 15):

### Short answer

**The Spirit and Guardian Nagas both get a new body**, their old body does not regenerate. It is up to the DM to decide where exactly this takes place.

*Longer answer follows...*

### A rejuvenated Spirit or Guardian Naga forms a new body

This is not made explicit in the stat blocks of either creature, but it is mentioned in the introductory text to Nagas in general (MM233):

> Nagas never feel the ravages of time or succumb to sickness. Even if it is struck down, a naga's immortal spirit reforms **in a new body** in a matter of days.

The Bone Naga introductory text also suggests that reinhabiting the same body (or at least skeleton) is a departure from the normal state of things:

> yuan-ti createad a necromantic ritual that could halt a naga's resurrection by transforming the living naga into a skeletal undead servitor.

### Where the rejuvenation takes place

In the description of rejuvenation of some other creatures we find an 'anchor' near which the new body is formed, for example Mummy Lord's heart or Lich's phylactery - see the relevant MM entries. In the Nagas' descriptions of rejuvenation we find no such 'anchor', so the exact location where the Naga's spirit takes a new body is up to the DM. A DM may decide that the old body functions as this 'anchor', but this is not essential and certainly not suggested by the rules as written. In the case of Guardian Nagas, it makes sense for them to rejuvenate (respawn) near the "places and items of magical powers" (MM 233) which they are guarding, though in the case of movable objects that could get interesting!