# How to (permanently) kill a Naga?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, edition-comparison

It has come to my attention that, at the very least in 5E, [Naga's are effectively immortal](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58848/how-does-naga-rejuvenation-work). When slain, they simply return to full HP in a matter of days. However, I have not managed to find any confirmation that the same is true in 3.5

Hence my question: Are Naga as immortal in 3.5 as they are in 5e? And if yes, then how could they be permanently put down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Nagas are not immortal in D&D 3.5.

The official D&D 3.5 [Monster Index](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/monsters) lists a great number of different nagas, but none of them have the ability to return to life when slain.

At best, they are exceptionally long-lived or immortal until slain, and some are difficult to kill, but once slain, none have the ability to return to life that their 5th edition partners possess. You can permanently kill a D&D 3.5 naga the same way you kill any creature.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see [on the 3.5's SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/naga.htm), none of the nagas have any kind of ability to *come back from the dead*, that mechanic is exclusive to 5th edition.

As for how to kill them, that is already spelled on their ability:

> **Rejuvenation**: If it dies, the naga returns to life in 1d6 days and regains all its Hit Points. Only a **wish spell** can prevent this trait from functioning.